# ASP.NET Redirect without processing the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I redirect, it still processes the View which will always error because I haven't set up a Model object.  How can I force the website using

```
RedirectPermanent("/page",true);
```

and not have to process the view page?

Comment: Just use return Redirect("path"). return statement is important here

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the return statement before the redirection, like

```
return RedirectPermanent("/page",true); //resource permanently moved
```

or

```
return Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return an object of type `IActionResult` from an action in controller. Now you only invoke `RedirectPermanent()` function which returns initialized object of type `RedirectResult` but MVC framework doesn't execute it.